# Arrays, sobrepasar el index máximo. PHP

Tags: php, array

La idea es la siguiente, dado un

```
$s = array('Hola', 'Adiós');
```

Siendo

```
$s[0] : Hola
$s[1] : Adiós
```

Entonces

```
$s[2] : Hola
```

En este ejemplo podría calcular el módulo y cuando el numero introducido fuese par, devolver hola e impar devolver adiós, sin embargo habrá más elementos (0 a X rango) dónde si se da X+N, N este comprendido entre 0 y X.

No sé si me explico, en defintiva, en un array el rango máximo es count($array)-1; pero mi idea es, que ese array pueda tener infinitas posiciones, repetidas secuencialmente.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias! :)

Comment: Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de lo que planteas ? ¿ resultado de que operación obtendrás ? ¿Por qué array infinito ? quieres obtener el `$array[$resultado]`  ? no termino de entender .

Comment: Con el módulo te vale, no hace falta que sea par o impar, si haces el módulo de `N%X` te devolverá siempre un valor entre 1 y X, solo tienes que restarle 1 para que sea entre 0 y X.

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que entiendo que desea *(espero no haber entendido mal)*, podría hacer es generar un `array` de acuerdo al número arrojado por el módulo . quizá haya funciones para esto pero para este ejemplo lo haremos con fors clásicos donde abarcaremos todos los posibles resultados.

El ejemplo funcionará para arrays no solo de dos elementos si no de más o menos *(1)* pero este último no tendría sentido pero bueno.

**Código** *(explicación en el código)*

```
function fillAndGet($array,$indice){
    //Si es indice negativo retornamos un mensaje personalizado
    if($indice<0) return '<br>Solo números positivos';
    // si está dentro del ranngo simplemente retornamos la posición
    if((int)$indice >= 0 && $indice < count($array)  ) {
        echo "<pre>". print_r($array,true)."</pre>";
        return $array[$indice];
    }
    //iniciamos en el indice final del array
    for ($i=count($array); $i < $indice ; ) { 
        //Iteramos los elementos de array
        foreach ($array as  $value) {
            // si la variable i es mayor a index no hace falta
            // rellenar con más valores y salimos con break
            if($i > $indice-1) break;
            // caso contrario simplemente agreamos el $valor 
            //iterado del array original
            $array[$i++] = $value;
        }
    }
    //esta linea es para demostración
    echo "<pre>". print_r($array,true)."</pre>";
    return $array[$indice-1];
}
$s = array('Hola','Mundo');
echo fillAndGet($s,10);
echo fillAndGet($s,5);
echo fillAndGet($s,1);
echo fillAndGet($s,0);
echo fillAndGet($s,-1);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/PurpleSolidOffice)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Un array "infinito" en php tiene un máximo: 2^32-1. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3036957/1423096

pareciera que estás definiendo el comportamiento de una función

```
 <?php

 function saludoModular($v){
     return $v%2?'Adiós':'Hola';
 }

 echo "15 -> ".saludoModular(15)."  42 -> ".saludoModular(42);
```

ó directamente el operador ternario

```
 <?php

 $v = 21;
 $s = $v%2?'Adiós':'Hola';

 echo "$v -> $s";
```

peeero si lo que quieres es un array de N+1 (incluye el 0) elementos alternando las palabras 'Hola' y 'Adiós':

```
 <?php

 $n = 15;
 $a = explode(',', str_repeat('Hola,Adiós,', $n/2+$n%2));
 $t = array_pop($a); // descarte el último

 var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer una función para que busque y muestre según el `$index`. Hice una función en el que le pasas el `array` y el `index` al cual querés mostrar.

```
$s = array('Hola', 'Adiós');
$s2 = array('Hola', 'Adiós', 'Chau', 'Bienvenido');

function arr($array, $index) {
  // Obtengo el total del array
  $count = count($array);
  // Obtengo el restante de la división sobre el total
  $index = $index % $count;
  // Devuelvo el valor correspondiente del array
  return $array[$index];
}

var_dump(arr($s, 0));
var_dump(arr($s, 1));
var_dump(arr($s, 2));
var_dump(arr($s, 3));
var_dump(arr($s, 123));

var_dump(arr($s2, 0));
var_dump(arr($s2, 1));
var_dump(arr($s2, 2));
var_dump(arr($s2, 3));
var_dump(arr($s2, 4));
var_dump(arr($s2, 123));
```

Salida:

```
string(4) "Hola"
string(6) "Adiós"
string(4) "Hola"
string(6) "Adiós"
string(6) "Adiós"

string(4) "Hola"
string(6) "Adiós"
string(4) "Chau"
string(10) "Bienvenido"
string(4) "Hola"
string(10) "Bienvenido"
```

[Aquí lo puedes chequear](https://ideone.com/oOotDG)